# Grading Students - Hackerrank

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

Here is my solution to [Grading Students](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grading/problem) courtesy of HackerRank. My code passes all tests in the testing suite but I feel like there could be a better implementation of it. But nonetheless, what are some pros/cons of my current implementation?
Thank you for answering.

```py
def gradingStudents(grades):
    rounded_grades = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade < 38:
            rounded_grades.append(grade)
        else:
            if grade % 5 == 0:
                rounded_grades.append(grade)
            else:
                difference = 0
                new_grade = grade
                while grade % 5 != 0:
                    difference += 1
                    new_grade += 1
                    if new_grade % 5 == 0:
                        break
                if difference < 3:
                    rounded_grades.append(new_grade)
                else:
                    rounded_grades.append(grade)
    return rounded_grades
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your code is pretty good. Nice job.
- I'd personally change the first `else` to an `elif` so you don't have as much indentation.
- Rather than using that while loop you can just use one `%` per number.

  For each number if you get the modulo then you can find out how much to add. 7 % 5 is 2. Where 5 - 2 is not less than 3.

  And so you can easily change the while to just `difference = 5 - grade % 5`
- You can merge `grade % 5 == 0` into the else.
- You can change the order and content of the ifs. This is as we don't need to call `list.append` three times, just mutate `grade`.

```py
def gradingStudents(grades):
    rounded_grades = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade >= 38:
            difference = 5 - grade % 5
            if difference < 3:
                grade += difference
        rounded_grades.append(grade)
    return rounded_grades
```

Since we know the range that anything modulo 5 is 0-4, we can just make a small lists that holds how much to round.

```py
ADDITIONS = [0, 0, 0, 2, 1]


def gradingStudents(grades):
    rounded_grades = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade >= 38:
            grade += ADDITIONS[grade % 5]
        rounded_grades.append(grade)
    return rounded_grades
```

You can also change the code to a list comprehension if you're that way inclined.

```py
ADDITIONS = [0, 0, 0, 2, 1]


def gradingStudents(grades):
    return [
        grade if grade < 38 else grade + ADDITIONS[grade % 5]
        for grade in grades
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your commentary. I very much prefer the first version that you wrote. List comprehensions are great and all but just seeing the first version is good enough for me.

Comment: No problem, happy I could help :)